# Dualboot: Windows does not show up when selecting boot priority

Tags: windows, boot, bios, linux-mint, dualboot

I dualboot windows 10 (21H1 build 19043.1110) and Linux Mint 22.04 on the same 2TB HDD. My motherboard is a Gigabyte H310M S2V 2.0. My BIOS version is F11 (I have never updated it). I can get into Windows on this "quick select" looking page that pops up right when I enter the BIOS:

[image: img]

The empty text one (for some reason) is Windows, the other 2 are both the same Linux (for some other reason). However, when I press Enter Setup and try to change the boot order, only the 2 Linux ones show up:

[image: img]

One day it just disappeared. Any help is appreciated. I also didn't mess around with any BIOS settings. These are my partitions if that's needed:

[image: img]

Edit: I ran a `bcdedit /enum all`:

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {5b718f94-fd85-11ed-8871-806e6f6e6963}
                        {9d2540e4-46a3-11eb-8822-806e6f6e6963}
                        {bootmgr}
timeout                 1

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  hu-HU
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {f3bc1b62-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
displaybootmenu         Yes

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {5b718f94-fd85-11ed-8871-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI
description             ubuntu

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {9d2540e4-46a3-11eb-8822-806e6f6e6963}
description             ST2000DM008-2FR102

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  hu-HU
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {f3bc1b64-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
displaymessageoverride  CommandPrompt
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {f3bc1b62-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Legacy

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {f3bc1b64-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
device                  ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume1]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{f3bc1b65-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Recovery Environment
locale                  hu-HU
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessage          Recovery
osdevice                ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume1]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{f3bc1b65-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

Resume from Hibernate
---------------------
identifier              {f3bc1b62-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winresume.efi
description             Windows Resume Application
locale                  hu-HU
inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {f3bc1b64-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
filedevice              partition=C:
filepath                \hiberfil.sys
bootmenupolicy          Standard
debugoptionenabled      No

Windows Memory Tester
---------------------
identifier              {memdiag}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\memtest.efi
description             Windows memóriadiagnosztika
locale                  hu-HU
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes

EMS Settings
------------
identifier              {emssettings}
bootems                 No

Debugger Settings
-----------------
identifier              {dbgsettings}
debugtype               Local

RAM Defects
-----------
identifier              {badmemory}

Global Settings
---------------
identifier              {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
                        {badmemory}

Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
identifier              {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
                        {hypervisorsettings}

Hypervisor Settings
-------------------
identifier              {hypervisorsettings}
hypervisordebugtype     Serial
hypervisordebugport     1
hypervisorbaudrate      115200

Resume Loader Settings
----------------------
identifier              {resumeloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}

Device options
--------------
identifier              {f3bc1b65-495d-11eb-b2f5-fe1816932a7b}
description             Windows Recovery
ramdisksdidevice        partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi
```

Comment: From within Windows display your BCD and edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound Edited. To my knowlege, the command lists the contents of the BCD file visually.

Comment: Might be a good idea to upgrade (carefully) to [BIOS F14](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/H310M-S2V-20-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).